# best way to execute mysql within php script

Tags: php, mysql

Im kind of new to mysql and trying out some scripts.

The one thing I dont understand is, why (it seems) mysql queries need to be within a php variable.

This for example is not working:

```
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="wmt";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wmt");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else echo "correct";
mysqli_query($con,"LOAD DATA INFILE 'TOP_QUERIES-avtentichno.com-20140627-223259.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS");
```

When simply writing PHP and I want to output some HTML I do it like this:

```
<?php
code ();
...
?>
Here goes my HTML without worry about escaping!
<?php
morephp();
?>
```

Is there a similar "trick" to execute mysql and avoid putting my sql queries in variables?

Comment: Maybe the *heredoc* notation would help? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php  though I'm not sure which variable you're talking about in your code.

Comment: right with didi - what variable? you mean $con?

Comment: I mean what comes after con

Comment: That's not a variable following `$con`, that's a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The double quote within the string needs to be escaped, because the string literal is enclosed in double quotes.

Within the context of the string literal, this:

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

should be replaced by this:

```
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
```

So that PHP doesn't see that double quote as the end of the string literal.

This isn't a SQL issue; and it's not an issue with variables. It's an issue with string literals in PHP.

Comment: thx, nice catch. I was looking for a way not to have to deal with escaping.

Comment: @user1721135: But "escaping" is _always_ going to have to be dealt with; not just in the context of PHP string literals, but also in the context of SQL, or any other programming language. Just like we have to deal with escaping "less than" characters in HTML `&lt;`. It's always going to be a deal.